# toggle classes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to toggle the className to 'active' on clicking the 'Follow' button. I have tried following the tutorials and guides on the react website and other references but had no luck. Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Cover.css';
import withStyles from '../../decorators/withStyles';
import Link from '../../utils/Link';
import Avatar from './Avatar';

import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

@withStyles(styles)
class Cover extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Cover">
        <div className="Cover-container">
          <div>
            <Avatar 
              username="hilarl" 
              profession="Web Developer" 
              location="New York, New York"
              status="I am here to protect my business, a bunch of kids are out to ruin me" />
              <div className="Cover-submenu-container">
                <div className="Cover-submenu-section">
                  .
                </div>
                <div className="Cover-submenu-section links">
                  <a href="#" className="Cover-submenu-link">
                    <i className="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" className="Cover-submenu-link">
                    <i className="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>

                // follow button

                <div className="Cover-submenu-section connect-menu">
                  <Button className="follow-btn" href="#">Follow</Button>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cover;
```

Would be great if somebody could helpout with this. Thanks

Comment: render () {
      let followClass = this.state.isFollowing? 'active':'';

Comment: Like Andreas Möller said make it dependent of the state or the props,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you render the Button with the active class.

```
render () {
  let isFollowing = this.state.isFollowing
  ...
      <Button className={`follow-btn ${isFollowing? ' active':''}`} ...
```

all you need to do now is to update isFollowing on button click.

Comment: probably the right approach so +1. But I personally like to handle these cases with inline styles. You wouldnt need this chaining up string crap.

Comment: like this: <Button className="follow-btn" style={isFollowing?style.active:{}} />

Comment: Either do all you styling inline or all in stylesheets mixing causes problems

Comment: its more reusable than concatenating strings :P But I agree I do most of my styling completly inline

Comment: @andreas Möller thanks for your solution, however I could not get it to work so I tried it this way: gist.github.com/hilarl/e03efd591322fee2fb2d but still getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFollowing' of null" Not sure what is wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: you need an initial state:
try this: https://gist.github.com/cullophid/81386f009388b0aa160b

Comment: I would recommend creating a FollowButton component, to better modularize your code